# Add a history table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

How do you implement on the back end, regardless of which table, when there is a data update, add a data to the history table.

I think there are two ways to do this, but I don't know the implementation details:

1.Add a method to the java backend that adds data to the history table when data changes in any table

2.Add trigger scripts to mysql, but this approach is too cumbersome and requires adding triggers to every data table

Comment: I think a trigger would be the best option. Keep in mind that it is a fully functional internal function of SQL. This makes that the programming language (in this case Java) must be independent to what it does in the database, in that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tech stack you're using, but for versioning and auditing you can use [Hibernate Envers](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/)

The main purpose of Hibernate Envers is to enable automatic tracking and recording of changes made to entities, which allows you to maintain a historical view of your data without requiring manual tracking of changes.

Comment: I had a problem, and I learned about mysql auditing, but it wasn't quite what I wanted, which was to add a history table to mysql specifically to record the history of data in other tables